# How to avoid saving a blank model which attributes can be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have two models with a HABTM association, let´s say book and author.

```
class Book
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end

class Author
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

The author has a set of attributes (e.g. first-name,last-name,age) that can all be blank (see validation).

```
validates_length_of :first_name, :maximum => 255, :allow_blank => true, :allow_nil => false
```

In the books_controller, I do the following to append all authors to a book in one step:

```
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
@book.authors.build(params[:book][:authors].values)
```

My question: What would be the easiest way to avoid the saving of authors which fields are all blank to prevent too much "noise" in the database?

At the moment, I do the following:

```
validate :must_have_some_data

def must_have_some_data
  empty = true
  hash = self.attributes
  hash.delete("created_at")
  hash.delete("updated_at")
  hash.each_value do |value|
    empty = false if value.present?
  end

  if (empty)
    errors.add_to_base("Fields do not contain any data.")
  end
end
```

Maybe there is an more elegant, Rails-like way to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little shorter

```
def must_have_some_data
  hash = self.attributes
  hash.delete("created_at")
  hash.delete("updated_at")
  errors.add_to_base("Fields do not contain any data.") if hash.select{|k,v| !v.blank?}.empty?
end
```

Actually I think, that you should validate not **all** attributes, but just specific attributes, which you are expecting to presence

```
def must_have_some_data
  valid_fields = ['first_name', 'second_name', 'last_name']
  errors.add_to_base("Fields do not contain any data.") if self.attributes.select{|k,v| valid_fields.include? k and !v.blank?}.empty?
end
```

**UPD**
In this situation you should also check authors fields in controller. So your authors fields must be in separate params group.

```
def create
  book = Book.new(params[:book])
  params[:authors].each do |author|
    book.authors.build(author) unless author.attributes.each{|k,v| !v.blank?}.empty?
  end
  if book.save
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you edit your answer, i´ll vote for it again (I accidentally hit the button twice). 
My problem is still the following:
When I do @book.save, the object is not saved if one of the associated authors has no values (because of the validation). This behaviour I want to prevent. Author fields can be empty and should not be saved when empty but the book should. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks again. With your code I got the following error: undefined method `attributes' for Array

This is how I solved it:

def create
  book = Book.new(params[:book])
  params[:authors].each do |key,value|
    book.authors.build(params[:authors][key]) unless params[:authors][key].select{|k,v| !v.blank?}.empty?
  end
  if book.save
    ...
  end
end

Comment: sorry, I've mistaken: `book.authors.build(author) unless author.attributes.each{|k,v| !v.blank?}.empty?` not authors.attributes... (singular) And actually you should look on accepts_nested_attributes_for as inkdeep suggested. I usually use this method for creating nested resources. But it works only on latest versions of rails

Answer (score 1):

put this in the books model:

```
validates_associated :authors, :on => :create
```

Unless you want invalid author objects to be silently ignored but not saved. Then the current solution is one way of solving it.

What version of rails are you using? [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M002182&name=accepts_nested_attributes_for) might be of use in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can change one line :)

```
def create
  book = Book.new(params[:book])
  params[:authors].each do |author|
    # book.authors.build(author) unless author.attributes.each{|k,v| !v.blank?}.empty?
    book.authors.build(author) unless author.all? {|key,val| val.empty?}
  end
  if book.save
    ...
  end
end
```